# Font Awesome icons not showing up, not sure why

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b2271d2a9b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have much experience with icons in general and I wanted to start using them to take my web dev skills to the next level, so I decided to go on YouTube to learn how to use Font Awesome from a tutorial, and I've watched a few tutorials but none have helped me, if you could tell me what's wrong with my code above me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: It works fine, where is the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is works fine (for me, the icon is shows up in the code snippet), you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried your code with sublime editor I can see FB icon on opening the html page

[image: See This Screenshot]

try taking your  tag inside span tag like

```
 <span> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"> </i> </span>
```

Try, and let me know whether it worked.